# Proper Spring Integration component for Object-to-Object transformation

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm currently receiving an object on an integration channel that is something like:

```
public class LargeObject {
    private final String name;
    private final Integer id;
}
```

I want to take the `name` from it, wrap it in my own object and send it to another channel.

So generally I want to transform the message payload in a way similar to `<integration:json-to-object-transformer>`.

I could just do it with a `<integration:service-activator>`, but I was wandering if there is component specifically dedicated for the job ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper component for this is a

```
<transformer/>
```

Assuming you have a constructor on your new object and a getName() method on your LargeObject, you can use a simple transformer with an expression...

```
<int:transformer expression="new foo.OtherObject(payload.name)"
    input-channel="foo" output-channel="bar" />
```

If you need more sophistication, simply make a POJO with this method...

```
public OtherObject transformIt(LargeObject input) {...}
```

and use...

```
<int:transformer ref="transformerPojo"
    input-channel="foo" output-channel="bar" />
```